# How could this bitmap be created?

Tags: bitmap, hex

Here is a bitmap, which has a strange header. How was it created? What kind of header is this?

http://zapodaj.net/1b0889852f46c.bmp.html (save the image and open it in hex editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a BMP file, that's a JPG file with wrong extension.

The header contains [0xFF markers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) and [the string "JFIF"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure) which is a clear sign for the JPG format.

Saving it on disk and opening with IrfanView gives the following warning:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer:)